# shaVe, shaMe, shaPe, shaDe, shaKe, shaRe --> What am I doing here? Does it have a name?

Tags: meaning

When you only change one letter from the word and it makes a new word. Does this have a name? Thanks so much in advance!

Also, I'm not sure if my question is 'language usage' related like in grammar but more of a trivial inquiry. I think it'll be important for me to know nonetheless.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a name. Letters are arbitrary and don't represent sounds well -- for instance, the vowel in _share_ isn't the same vowel as in _shave_. But, if you substitute sounds for letters, [ʃeⁱv, ʃeⁱm, ʃeⁱp, ʃeⁱd, ʃeⁱk] constitute a set of minimal pairs for for the final phonemes /v, m, p, d, k/.  I.e, the fact that these words have different meanings indicates native speakers can distinguish and produce them, so they're all separate phonemes (at least in final position).

Comment: This does sort of relate to the concept of a [word ladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_ladder) or word chain, which is described as a "single letter substitution".

Comment: But not in English; only in games.

Comment: @John That first comment sounds an awful lot like a full answer.

Comment: this is extremely common practice in **voice or accent coaching** and **singing lessons**.  it's a good question, does it have a name?

Comment: Why not we coin a new name for that?!!!:)

Comment: thank you all! also, why are some comments showing as replies and others as 'answers'?

Answer (score 2):

A game of this sort is called *Word Ladders* in Rudolph Castown's article "[The Arithmetic of Word Ladders](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1327&context=wordways)." *Word Ways* 1 (1968), 165--159. Word Ways is a journal of word games, or recreational linguistics. The article is mentioned in Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* Vol. 4A.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing depends on the context of the situation. If you are using letter substitution for say, a puzzle or a cipher, then that would usually be considered a method of cryptography, just as an example.

If you're asking if there is an identifiable word in English that means substituting a single letter, then no. Your best bet would be calling it, as Catija said, "single letter substitution".